# Why does this variable equal a number and a character?

Tags: c, pointers

While debugging this code snippet here:

```
int main () {
   char str[] = "Stackoverflow";
   char a = *str;
   return 0;
}
```

Why does `a` show as `83 'S'`?

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, but `a` holds only `S`, right?

Comment: @drizer `'S'` and `83` are the same thing.

Comment: Wow, I just found out that `char a = 83` stores `S` in `a`. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `a` only holds 'S' because when you dereference an array, it points to the first element.

Comment: Now for a slight bit more clarification, the C standard does not guarantee that characters have ASCII representation.  Other character encodings can be used.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons are you an old EBCDIC developer?

Comment: `char`s are, in fact, a lower range integer, typically `-128` to `127`(or `0` to `256`). You can do all kinds of integer arithmetic on them: `'4' + 3 == '7';`, `'5' * 84 = <something, barring overflow>;`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons what do you mean? Mind providing some examples?

Comment: @bruceg No, but I do like to dig into the standard and be aware of what is inherent to C rather than taking things for granted.  Been burned in the past when moving to a different system that did not act the same way as what I had been accustomed to (not related to character encoding).

Comment: @drizer it would be legal to use, for example, `UTF-8` as a character encoding.

Comment: But do we choose to do that? Does it use the ASCII by default?

Comment: For the most part, don't worry about it.  Try not to do things that rely on a particular encoding but rather use functions that abstract that away.  So if you wanted to convert a letter from lower to upper case, don't subtract 32 from the number to accomplish this (lower case numbers are 32 higher than their uppercase equivalent in ASCII), but instead use `toupper()`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I understand what you mean, thanks for the help.

Comment: @drizer You are using a literal string so the character encoding is determined by the "execution charset" the compiler is told to use. That's not ASCII in typical case. If the string came from outside the program then whoever provides the text must either follow your plan or tell the program's theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

83 is the [ASCII](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange) code for uppercase letter 's'.

`*str` is equal to writing `str[0]` so in this case the first memory slot of the array `str` which corresponds to the character 'S'

Answer (score 5):

I think you might want to have more than one thing clarified:

First, pointer `str` points to the first character of a sequence of character values in memory, i.e. `S`, `t`, `a`, ...
Then, `*str` dereferences this pointer, i.e. it reads the value of the character to which `str` points. Hence `*str` yields `S`.
Statement `char a = *str` assigns the value `S` to variable `a` of type `char`, which represents a portion of memory capable of storing one character. Usually, `char` is an 8 bit signed (or unsigned) integral value, and any simple character is therefore represented by a value between -127 and +128 (the range of signed 8 bit values). The character value `S`, for example, seems to be represented as integral value 83 according to ASCII. Whether a system uses ASCII or some other character set is system defined, but ASCII is by far the most common character set today.
So `S` and `83` are actually the same thing, it's just that when a terminal interprets value `83` to be printed as character, it prints `S`. The other way round, if we interpret `S` as integral value, a terminal would print `83`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf("'S' as integral value: %d\n", 'S');
    printf("83 as character value: %c\n", 83);

    char c1 = 'S';
    char c2 = 83;

    if (c1 == c2) {
        printf("c1 and c2 are equal.\n");
    } else {
        printf("c1 and c2 are not equal.\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'S' as integral value: 83
83 as character value: S
c1 and c2 are equal.
```

Answer (score 1):

Computers understand everything as numbers: Characters, strings, photos, videos, audio ... etc. Everything is a number inside a computer and thus people wondered how to represent characters.

And because of this fact, they decided to encode characters as numbers so that every character has a corresponding number that encodes it inside the computer.

Throughout history, many character encoding schemes (A matching between characters and numbers) have been worked out but one of them is very famous and almost used everywhere : It's called [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character encoding. ASCII is a 7-bits encoding that represents all numerical characters and Latin alphabet characters (Uppercase and lowercase) beside some other symbols.

By default, your system provides ASCII input to your C program and thus, internally, this input is stored in memory as ASCII standard says. For instance, when you type A on your keyboard, the keyboard sends the value 65 (This is the decimal value of the character A in  the ASCII standard. Internally, it is sent as a sequence of 1000001101 because computers work in binary) to your program. Your program stores this value (65) inside a memory location specified by a variable (`char c;`). When you ask the computer to print this character, it checks the ASCII value stored in the character's variable and then figures out a way how to draw the matching symbol on the screen.

In C, strings are just a sequence (Or an array) of characters. When you hold a pointer to a string, it actually points to the first character of the string (The character array). If you advance the pointer by 1, you will point to the second character and so on. So, if you dereference your original pointer (That points to the first character), you will get the ASCII value of the character stored in that position (The first position) and thus in your case you get 83 which corresponds to the symbol 'S'.

The program below shows all ASCII characters and their graphical representation : Some few characters might not have a visual representation because they are used for controlling input and terminal, especially, the first few characters (First 34 values).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
       /* Unsigned to avoid integer overflow in the loop below */
        unsigned char c; 

        /* ASCII is 7-bit so it can represent 
           2^7 = 128 (from 0 to 127) symbols */

        for (c = 0; c < 128; c++) 
                printf ("ASCII value of %c = %d\n", c, c);

        return 0;
}
```